# How to separate Time portions for comboBox

Tags: c#, database, string, datetime

C# problem ...I am recieving from a database a datetime type 1/1/1900 08:00:00 AM and I want to take only the time portion and populate three comboBoxes with HH MM (AM or PM).  I have to do the same thing for two diffent sets of data I'm getting...Have no idea how to do it..

Can anyone help?

This is what i got for the moment...I am a newbie :0)

```
    DateTime bh = Convert.ToDateTime(puf.GetResults["Begin_Hour"].ToString());
    DateTime eh = Convert.ToDateTime(puf.GetResults["End_Hour"].ToString());
    string bhs=bh.ToShortTimeString();
    string ehs=eh.ToShortTimeString();
```

Comment: Where do you get trouble? Any exception message?

Answer (score 0):

What you have ought to work fine to just get the time.

You could use the `ToString()` method which has an overload where you can give your custom formats. Refer to this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx).

So you can use `bhs.ToString("t");` to print the hour, minutes and AM/PM.

Answer (score 0):

Use this (dt is your DateTime object)

```
bhs.Format("{0:t}", dt);
```

The result will be in your desired format:
 "4:05 PM"

You can read more here: [String Format for DateTime](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using objects/datatables, it might be a good option to just set the DisplayMember/ValueMember properties in conjunction with the FormatString property. Set the `FormattingEnabled = true`, `FormatString = "t"`, `DisplayMember = ValueMember = "[Begin_Hour|End_Hour]"`.

Note that [|] syntax is borrowing from Regex, meaning either value will work. Then just assign the underlying datasource to the ComboBox.DataSource property. It's usually a good idea to handle display/formatting on your UI elements and keep the data elements unchanged, which is why a lot of controls provide these various data display properties.